# How to play the platform CLICK sound in Jetpack Compose Button click

Tags: audio, android-jetpack-compose

It seems Jetpack Compose [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Button(kotlin.Function0,%20androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,%20kotlin.Boolean,%20androidx.compose.foundation.InteractionState,%20androidx.compose.material.ButtonElevation,%20androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,%20androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,%20androidx.compose.material.ButtonColors,%20androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,%20kotlin.Function1)) click has no default sound. How can I add the standard [CLICK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SoundEffectConstants#CLICK) sound to button clicks?

Comment: I also noticed that, IMO the system click sound should play out-of-the-box on Compose buttons and on everything where you set a `.clickable` modifier. You might want to report that to Google on issue tracker

Answer (score 4):

I tried this answer and worked...

[Can't play sound on button click using playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362698/cant-play-sound-on-button-click-using-playsoundeffectsoundeffectconstants-clic)

```kotlin
val context = AmbientContext.current
...

OutlinedButton(
    content = { Text("OK") },
    onClick = {
        val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        audioManager.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK,1.0f)
    }
)
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like a workaround rather than an idiomatic solution. I would expect some specific argument of Button() or its Modifier(), but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 0):

```
fun (() -> Unit).withSound(context: Context): () -> Unit = {
  (context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager)
    .playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK)
  this()
}
```

And then use it like,

```
@Composable
fun ClickyButton(
  text: String,
  enabled: Boolean = true,
  onClick: () -> Unit,
  modifier: Modifier,
) {
  Button(
      onClick = onClick.withSound(LocalContext.current),
      ...
```